# Best SVN backend benchmarks

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, fsfs

Are there benchmarks about the usage, speed, reliability of svn back-end databases?

- SQLite
- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- BerkeleyDB
- Flatfile system

Let's say we have 20 people working on the repository concurrently. What to choose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FSFS backend is the most well-tested and stable of the lot. For only 20 people, you are not likely to have any performance problems at all.

Answer (score 7):

Today, you only have 2 choices if you are hosting your own server:

1. BDB (BerkeleyDB)
2. FSFS (direct filesystem)

These days, FSFS is the preferred backend, and has been for a number of years.  There is almost no advantage to BDB, and I think it is only around for legacy compatibility.  FSFS is the default on any current SVN release.  A lot of the SVN binary distributions don't even have BDB support compiled in.

More info:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.planning.html#svn.reposadmin.basics.backends

Note that custom implementations are possible.  For example, [Google Code](https://code.google.com/) has a custom SVN backend based on their [Bigtable architecture](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/03/faster-subversion-hosting.html).  Not sure if any other SVN hosting providers do something similar.

Additionally, the SVN developers have been working on a replacement for FSFS called [FSX or FS2](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2013-07/0059.shtml).  It is still experimental though.

Comment: Now where was it that I thought I read that recent versions of Subversion supported more backends than just BDB and FSFS? I just checked the release notes for 1.6.x and there was no mention of other backends (except for SQLite for other purposes), so I must have been mistaken. Regardless, today I wouldn't choose anything but FSFS even if there were others available.